# Azure Metrics for Virtual Machine

Tags: azure

I am trying to obtain metrics for an Azure Virtual Machine. The standard Insights API provided doesn't provide all the metrics. Upon more reading I found that these metrics are stored in Azure Storage Accounts under different tables. Is there a way to make an API call to these tables and retrieve the metrics ?

Comment: What metrics are you referring to? Also - there are lots of posts here and elsewhere talking about how to read metrics that are stored in Azure Storage.

Comment: Well I am unable to get in particular Memory Metrics for a VM from the standard API available. Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt743622.aspx . Also I just downloaded the Azure Storage Explorer and some tables contain the metric information. But I couldn't find any good documentation on how to retrieve it using API.

Answer (score 0):

There are two categories of metrics for Azure Virtual Machine -- host level metrics that are derived from Hyper V performance counters and the guest level metrics that come from within the VM itself.

For host level metrics, the Insights REST API provides access to this data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-metrics

For guest metrics such as Memory metrics, you need to install the diagnostics agent to collect this data to one of the supported sink types such as storage account, event hub, or Application Insights. If you collect this data to storage account or event hub, you need to use the standard storage API or event hub API to access this data.  Specifically for storage, the data will be stored in WADPerformanceCountersTable in Azure table storage. There is no additional REST API to retrieve this data outside of the existing storage API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics